# SQL COUNT not giving me the correct results

Tags: mysql, sql

So, I have this articles table and I want to find how many published articles are there for a specific section, say, section 1. This is the SQL I used:

```
  SELECT count(*) as numStories 
   FROM noticia WHERE not_flgpublicar = 'S' AND not_sec = 1;
```

and the result I got:

```
+------------+
| numStories |
+------------+
|          0 |
+------------+
```

But that's not right, as I know the section exists and there are several published articles in that section. In fact, it doesn't matter which section I use, the SQL always returns a count of zero!

Then I did this:

```
 SELECT not_sec, count(*) as numStories 
 FROM noticia WHERE not_flgpublicar='S' GROUP BY not_sec;
```

And the result I got:

```
+---------+------------+
| not_sec | numStories |
+---------+------------+
|    NULL |          8 |
|       0 |       3583 |
|       1 |      20151 |
|       2 |      15979 |
|       3 |       8233 |
|       4 |       8406 |
|       5 |       3493 |
|       6 |       3952 |
|       7 |       1237 |
|       8 |       1213 |
|       9 |        108 |
|      11 |         44 |
|      12 |         12 |
+---------+------------+
```

As you can see, there ARE several articles for each section, but the first SQL statement still won't work. I've found a way to get the correct count by doing this:

```
SELECT count(*) as numStories 
FROM noticia WHERE not_flgpublicar='S' GROUP BY not_sec HAVING not_sec = 1;
```

which (finally) returns:

```
+------------+
| numStories |
+------------+
|      20151 |
+------------+
```

but I'd really, really like to know why the first SQL statement isn't working, because as far as I understand, it should work.

Any ideas, please? This is really blowing my mind.

EDIT - More info: The `not_sec` field type is `int(11)` and the `not_flgpublicar` field type is `char(1)`. The engine is MySQL v. 5.6.41. The table structure has more than 50 fields, so I'm hesitant to it here.

EDIT 2 - More strangeness. When I try to find the stories that are NOT published (`not_flgpublicar` equalling 'N') it works:

```
mysql> SELECT count(*) as numStories 
          FROM noticia 
          WHERE not_flgpublicar = 'N' AND not_sec = 1;
+------------+
| numStories |
+------------+
|         12 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

but it still doesn't work if I try to find the published ones:

```
mysql> SELECT count(*) as numStories 
          FROM noticia 
          WHERE not_flgpublicar = 'S' AND not_sec = 1;
+------------+
| numStories |
+------------+
|          0 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

I even tried LIKE:

```
mysql> SELECT count(*) as numStories 
          FROM noticia 
          WHERE not_flgpublicar LIKE 'S' AND not_sec = 1;
+------------+
| numStories |
+------------+
|          0 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

BUT, if I do this:

```
mysql> SELECT count(*) as numStories 
          FROM noticia 
          WHERE not_flgpublicar LIKE '%S' AND not_sec = 1;
+------------+
| numStories |
+------------+
|      20151 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

...it works.

The `not_flgpublicar` field is `char(1)`, so it's not like there can be more than one character in that field (I checked). Collation is `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` for all fields.

Comment: Your first statement should have worked. What data type is the `not_sec` field?

Comment: "But that's not right" MySQL never lies...Provide table structure with example data which contains the `not_flgpublicar = 'S'` data ... Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "Help others reproduce the problem".. Besides are you sure you didn't get a warning after executing the first query? Try executing `SHOW WARNINGS` after that query.

Comment: I've added some more info about the database in my question. Executing `SHOW WARNINGS` after the query gave me an empty set.

Comment: Can you create a sqlfiddle with sample data that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Is there an index on either column?

Comment: Try repairing the table.

Comment: is it possible you somehow copied and pasted a hidden character into your query...perhaps try writing the query from scratch

Comment: I would drop and recreate the indexes.

Comment: @Barman The table is InnoDB, so I can't repair it. Both of the columns have indexes.

Comment: @Ctznkane525, nope, I did what you suggested and still didn't work.

Comment: @CetinBasoz, I'll try that.

Comment: @CetinBasoz, I dropped the index on the `not_flgpublicar` column and it worked! I recreated the index and, again, it stopped working! WTF?? Dropping and recreating the index on the `not_sec` didn't have any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, looks like this might actually be a MySQL bug.  See here:

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=81031

Try the following before your SQL statement to verify:

```
SET SESSION optimizer_switch="index_merge_intersection=off";
```

Comment: It is indeed a bug! That worked! This was driving me crazy, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

SELECT count(0) as numStories 
   FROM noticia WHERE not_flgpublicar = 'S' AND not_sec = 1;